# What makes New York and San Francisco special on salary calculator?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

In [Salary Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator?p=1&e=1&s=1.0&l=1), there is an option as location for New York and San Francisco for United States as a country.

[image]

When this option selected, it almost adds $10.000 to the salary. I checked [Salary transparency at Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/salary-transparency/) and [How We Assess Skill Level](https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/skills/web-developer?e=1&l=1) links but I couldn't find any information about them. I searched these cities in here also but nothing much.

What makes these cities special for salary? So expensive to live? Taxes?

I'm from Turkey, so I don't know if there is a local reason.

**EDIT**: [How Do Software Developers in New York, San Francisco, London and Bangalore Differ?](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/How-Do-Developers-in-New-York-San-Francisco-London-and-Bangalore-Differ)

Comment: They're both very expensive: https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living/index/north-america

Comment: Joel Spolsky lives in NY and Jeff Atwood in SF. Coincidence?

Comment: @Liam Switch to UK and it shows London instead.

Comment: ha, well, I didn't really pay attention to that @DavidG....

Comment: @MSalters Yes that's a coincidence. Jeff Atwood isn't even with the company anymore. It's likely because the *company* is based in NY and most developers congregate there or in SF/San Jose, so they are acutely aware of increased living costs in those places.

Comment: it seems like Washington DC should be included in that list as well

Comment: SF is expensive, yes.  But don't move to Seattle.  It's already bad and getting worse.  Seriously.  Stay where you are, move to Austin, whatever.  Just not Seattle.

Comment: @davidbak Yeah, Seattle has a lot of the same issues as SF. Tons of devs moving in driving up demand for housing and lots of water in the way of building said housing close to the city.

Comment: I think that cost of housing/living is only part of the picture.  It also matters how many companies in the area place a high degree of importance on getting the top talent.  The top engineers also tend to congregate in areas where more companies have a strong engineering culture (tech hubs).  Top engineers are going to demand higher compensation, and companies with a strong engineering culture are willing to pay those higher salaries.

Comment: Sydney should have a checkbox in "I don't see my country".

Comment: It is because of cost of living. That said, just because I chose not to live where it is expensive is not a valid reason to offer me $10K less.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson  Sure it is.  Try to rent a (modest, old, small) condo in this area before making that assertion.   I pay $1500/month higher here for a modest condo than if I could live in my (big) rental home in another (great but less expensive) city region.  That's $18K *before taxes*.

Comment: Despite these two cities being more expensive, the additional 10K appear to be arbitrary. Also, what makes a city *expensive* so that it "deserves" those additional $ ? What's the threshold? Shouldn't this be more of a gradient than a fixed value?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To expand on what Pekka's comment said...

NY and San Francisco are both high density urban areas, with limited housing (i.e. it's not as easy to build more) that makes it very expensive to live there. I used [CNN's cost of living calculator](http://money.cnn.com/calculator/pf/cost-of-living/) and compared Jacksonville, FL (5th largest US city by area, but nowhere near the population, housing density, or market demand) to San Francisco. Note the massive disparity in housing

[image]

Comment: "Housing 255% more". http://crooksandliars.com/files/primary_image/15/02/gun_emoji.jpg

Comment: @Pekka웃 getting out of Jacksonville may be worth it...

Comment: I was going to suggest Boston would have a similar adjustment but I see the housing costs in Boston are "only" 112% more.

Comment: @Pekka웃 it's spelled 

Comment: Saying Jacksonville is the "6th largest U.S. city" is rather misleading. When considering whole metropolitan areas, [it's actually 40th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_metropolitan_areas_of_the_United_States). For only the actual city limits, Jacksonville is 12th, but that's kind of a misleading measure, since lots of metro areas are technically divided into several different cities and, especially for the larger cities, lots of people live in the suburbs. But, yeah, SF and NYC are insanely expensive places to live. Even with the +$10k, you're still better off elsewhere in the U.S.

Comment: @reirab perhaps he meant land area, where Jacksonville, FL is actually 5th largest?

Comment: @mgarciaisaia thanks, was looking for that!

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, that's possible.

Comment: @reirab It's not exactly an apples-to-apples comparison(I cleaned the verbiage up some to clarify), but, in this same vein, I often see people ask why jobs in the SE pay so little. Jax is a decent comparison for this purpose. If I wanted pure shock value I would have gone with Albany, GA. 331%, but not exactly a place you'd see on SO Jobs either.

Comment: @Machavity Oh, I completely agree on the cost difference. When I punch in my city (also in the SE) vs. SF, it shows +350% for housing, which I would say is actually a very low estimate. My 2,000 sqft brick house on an acre is worth maybe $180k. From a quick search, slightly smaller houses in SF appear to go for around $1.2M and those are on lots with less square footage than my house. The cost of housing there is just insane. For a similarly-sized city, though, Houston, Atlanta, or Miami would probably be a better comparison.

Comment: Ha! @reirab do you have any idea how much that would be worth in the centre of London! [2000 sq foot plot in a re-developed apartment in Central London](https://www.redrow.co.uk/developments/blake-tower-402232/availability/plot162) £3,650,000 (thats nearly $4.5M).

Comment: @reirab If you had an acre in SF, even without a house on it, I'm pretty sure you could retire today.

Comment: Does the 255% more mean that you will be paying 255% more in housing if you move or will you be saving 255% more?

Comment: @JohnOdom you will be paying more. A $1,000/mo rent would become --for an equivalent unit-- $2,550/mo rent.

Comment: @ArtB The rent would actually be 255% aka $2,550 more, so $3,550/month total

Comment: @ArtB Yeah, it's not just 255%, but 255% _more_, so actually 355% of what you're paying now. Also, it's kind of hard to _save_ 255%, unless they start paying you 155% of what you're paying now. :)

Comment: @Liam Yeah, parts of NYC are like that, too. The concept of spending millions of dollars on an apartment still seems crazy to me, but I guess if you work close to there and are making millions of dollars, then it could be worthwhile. Or if you're just extremely wealthy and want to live there because you can. Anyway, yay for free markets where we can all choose what works best for us individually.

Comment: Note that in general, tightly bounded cities that can't grow out tend to be worth more.  Portland has laws limiting sprawl and encouraging city density and most people find it to be one of the more livable cities (and is retaining property values).  Hawaii is also amazingly expensive and physically bounded..  Allowing unbounded sprawl leads to cities that aren't terribly usable/walkable (Like Los Angeles) with enormous suburbs that require nasty commutes.. A nearby walkable downtown seems to directly relate to housing price across the region...